# miss /dev/bpf in freebsd

Tags: freebsd, tcpdump

I'm using tcpdump in freebsd, and I got the following error:

```
$ /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i bge0
tcpdump: (cannot open device) /dev/bpf: No such file or directory
```

a few google search indicate that the presudo berkley packet fillter device is shomehow missing. so how can I solve it?

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/bpf*` print?

Answer (score 0):

There is no [`bpf`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bpf&sektion=4) device node likely because there is [no bpf device present](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/faq/networking.html#idp76652464), it's a kernel build time configuration option which you may be missing.

You'll need to add/enable it in your [kernel configuration](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/kernelconfig-config.html), rebuild, and reboot...

You can check if `bpf` is available by seeing if there are any kernel state parameters set:

```
sysctl net.bpf
```

At some point in the not too distant past FreeBSD changed from enumerated `/dev/bpf0` `/dev/bfp1` etc. devices to a single "cloneable" `/dev/bpf` device. There *might* be a chance that your `tcpdump` or `libpcap` is too old for your kernel, or vice versa, and it's not looking for the right device file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have compiled a custom kernel, it could be that

```
device bpf
```

is missing from your kernel config